# Get product image for invoice email in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, shipping, invoice

I like to get customer **product image** in "invoice email template"

I had add code in my below file

> Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/invoice/default.phtml

```
<td>
        <?php 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product_id = $_item->getProductId();
        $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

        $_imagehelper = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
        $image_url = $_imagehelper->init($product, 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->getUrl();

        ?>
          <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName(); ?>" />
    </td>
```

Image shows default for customer new invoice template.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an image in email template. you should use below code in order/invoice/ship item layout handle.

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product_id = $_item->getProductId();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$_imagehelper = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$image_url = $_imagehelper->init($product, 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->getUrl();
?>
<img src="<?php echo $image_url ; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName(); ?>" />
```

For example to display image in Invoice email template for simple product renderer type.

Copy "sales_email_order_invoice_renderers.xml" to Vendor\YourModuleName\View\frontend\layout\sales_email_order_invoice_renderers.xml and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.invoice.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems" name="sales.email.order.invoice.renderers.default" as="default" template="Vendor_YourModuleName::email/items/invoice/default.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create default.phtml at Vendor\YourModuleName\templates\email\items\invoice\default.html and paste below code.

```
<?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
<?php $_order = $block->getItem()->getOrder(); ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product_id = $_item->getProductId();
        $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

        $_imagehelper = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
        $image_url = $_imagehelper->init($product, 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->getUrl();

        ?>
          <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName(); ?>" />
    </td>
    <td class="item-info<?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?> has-extra<?php endif; ?>">
        <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
        <p class="sku"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('SKU') ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)).'test' ?></p>
        <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?>
            <dl>
                <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
                    <dt><strong><em><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  nl2br($option['value']) ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
            <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item->getOrderItem())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
    </td>
    <td class="item-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQty() * 1 ?></td>
    <td class="item-price">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getItemPrice($_item->getOrderItem()) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**P.S I recommend to do not use objectmanager in phtml file directly instead override block class and use dependency.**

Answer (score 1):

Replace  `$_item->getProduct()` that used in the order email template with `$_item->getOrderItem()->getProduct()`

`$_item` in the invoice is different then `$_item` in the order and need to use `getOrderItem()` function to retrieve the order item object.

Comment: Still image shows a magento placeholder image