# Unable to add Product image in New order Email Magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2.3, email, product-images

I have tried below 2 solutions:

1. [Get product image for invoice email in magento 2.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266248/get-product-image-for-invoice-email-in-magento-2-3)
2. [(Solved) Magento 2, Add product image in all transaction emails(shipment, invoice, credit memo)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219789/solved-magento-2-add-product-image-in-all-transaction-emailsshipment-invoic)

I am using Claue theme, I pasted the below code in invoice/default.phtml & order/default.phtml, then did a `setup:static-content:deploy -f`. Created new Order, but I do not see the product image in email only the items as shown in the image below.

**PATH:**

> app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Bundle/templates/email/order/items/order

**CODE:**

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product_id = $_item->getProductId();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$_imagehelper = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$image_url = $_imagehelper->init($product, 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->getUrl();
?>
<img src="<?php echo $image_url ; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName(); ?>" />
```

**This is what I see in email:**

[image]

I am using Magento 2.3.5-p1, I am not sure if I am pasting the code in correct block. I pasted it below `<tr class="bundle-item bundle-parent">` and above `<td class="item-info">`.

Comment: You can try this one : https://magecomp.com/magento-2-product-images-order-view.html

Comment: @DhirenVasoya thanks for the reply. I actually trying to send picture in the email, that extension I think is for the `customer` order view in account panel.

Comment: Ok you can use same concept for the email files which render the product.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya please read my question...

Comment: You have put code only for bundle items, you need to put this on all items in generally files.

Comment: I only have "email" folder in this specific Magento_Bundle directory, I have search it with `find` command. Other email directory I has is in vendor/, but it does not contain `.phtml` files.

Comment: Please do not use objectManager directly in the .phtml files, it objects Magento object manager pattern. You will need to either preference or inject your block instead.

Comment: well nothing is working for me. I still wasn't able to figure it out. that how to receive images in email of product